# coalgebra/algebra of the identity endfunctor

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a small/locally small category and let $T:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an endofunctor. One can then have $T$-algebras and $T$-coalgebras in the usual way: for $X,Y \in \mathbb{C}$, $f_x: TX \to X$ and $f_y: Y \to TY$, we have the algebra $(X, f_x)$ and the coalgebra $(X, f_y)$.

Can anything interesting at all be said about such algebras/coalgebras in the degenerate case when $T$ is an identity functor in $\mathbb{C}$? All I could think of is the obvious fact that such algebra/coalgebra are trivially self dual (and obviously bialgebras for $T$).

Any pointers on references connecting algebras to coalgebras (apart from the apparent duality) would be appreciated!

Comment: They're just sets equipped with an endomorphism. These are sometimes called discrete dynamical systems. What do you mean by "interesting"?

Comment: You mean elements of $\mathbb{C}$ with an endomorphism? Thanks, could you let me know any reference that talks about discrete dynamical systems? Wikipedia entry says these are some kinda transition systems that have discrete time steps.. Interesting as in, anything peculiar about the final coalgebra (I guess it is just the `gfp' of id functor), intial coalgebra, standard morphisms, lax/oplax morphism and such. I can't state anything extra about each of them...

Comment: In universal algebra these are called *monounary algebras*.